# Editing session data of a user who is logged in

Tags: php

Is it possible to edit the session data of a user who has logged in?

Eg. User norman logs in, and the following session cookie is set $_SESSION['addPost']=0

This means a user can add posts. Lets say I want to block that user from adding posts. I need to set that cookie to 1. Can i change the cookie value? Because, untill a user logs out and logs in again, it will not change, and he'll still be able to add posts.

How can this be done?

Comment: I would highly recommend the usage of cookies. It would be much eaiser to manipulate data from the database than from the presets $_SESSION has placed.

Comment: Why not reset the individual $_SESSION option?

Comment: You can only access the $_SESSION variable within PHP, and within PHP can only be accessed with the user access the page.

Answer (score 0):

Do not edit the session variable. There's much better approach for this purpose.

Use one more column in `users` table named `post_access`. If you allow Norman to post, its value would be 1, while blocked user will get 0.

Let's say you have blocked a user from posting, so you have changed the value in `post_access` column to 0 in `users` table.

Now in the script of your **post creation**, before posting the data, make a condition if user's post access is set to 1 or not by comparing with the new queried user data from table 'users' using session name of author.

Sample:

```
  $userdata = get( 1 from "users" where user = "$_SESSION['user']"); //don't mind the get function. Use your own QUERIES. Just mind the logic. 
  $post_access = $userdata['post_access']; 
  if($post_acess == 1){
     //post the data
  }else{
     //Bro you are blocked
  }
```

This would be most effective way to control posts.